# `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` does not work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to display list of entities from Core Data in UITableView. In every cell of table I want to display info from entity but also additional info from entity's relationship entity.

That is a problem because during scrolling UITableView CoreDate asking for entity's relationship, one by one.

```
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e26f1f7feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p23121>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0003s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e240bb7feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p20920>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0003s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e287177feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p24659>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0003s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e2ce6b7feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p29196>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ?  
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0004s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e281bf7feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p25081>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
```

I checked documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html) and I found "prefetching" technic. Sounds great.

I used it in the code:

```
let fetchRequest = Animal.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDesc
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["animalActivitySettingBase"]
```

and I checked logs again:

```
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.1825s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.1862s for 10437 rows.
CoreData: annotation: Prefetching with key 'animalActivitySettingBase'.  Got 10437 rows.
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.5184s for 11031 rows.
```

Thats great. Relationship has been prefetchied. But...

When I scroll down UITableView, again CoreData asking:

```
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e26f1f7feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p23121>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0003s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e240bb7feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p20920>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0003s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e287177feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p24659>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0003s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e2ce6b7feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p29196>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ?  
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0004s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x925e06e281bf7feb <x-coredata://D99D4673-2788-4E00-90D6-811007DDF5AA/AnimalActivitySettingBase/p25081>
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGID, t0.ZACTIVITYTAGSTATUS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
```

#### PS

Changing `returnsObjectsAsFaults` to `true\false` do not fix it.

#### PS2

I am using iOS10 CoreData API `NSPersistentContainer`. I am fetching on `viewContext`.

Comment: Let me get this straight: your fetch time is 0.5 seconds - enough to be noticeable delay for the user and your time to fault each cell is 0.003 seconds which is as close to instant as you could hope for.  And your question is how can you make the initial fetch time MORE to make the fault time LESS?

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I asked wrong. Performance is good. My question is, why Core Data’ requests appears when I set ‘prefetch’?

Comment: I suspect that `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` is a hint and not a command.  The docs are ambiguous.  Consider the case where there is enough memory to fetch the entities, but not enough to also load all the relationships into memory.  I'd expect in that case for the `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` to be ignored.